# Django: putting more context in get_context_data in class-based-view

Tags: django

I do know that to put more context in a listview in django, we can just something like:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        b = 9
        context['num'] = b
        return context
```

and with that, we can use num in our template file.

But let's say I want to variables to be placed in the context, what do I do?

```
b = 9
a = 10 
context['a', 'b'] = a, b
```

and then I refered to this in my html template by directly calling {{a}} or {{b}}, no errors shows up, but nothing shows up either.

I think I have some misconception about a basic dictionary, and django adds confusion to it because it seems like you can't use () or [] inside of {{}}, by the way can someone answer why we can't use () or [] inside of the html code inside of {{}}?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`context` is just a dictionary, so you can write it like:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    b = 9
    a = 10
    context['a'] = a
    context['b'] = b
    return context
```

or you can use a `.update(..)` call, and add the elements in a single function call:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    b = 9
    a = 10
    context.update(a=a, b=b)
    return context
```

> why we can't use `()` or `[]` inside of the html code inside of `{{ }}`?

Because Django templates are deliberately limited, to prevent people from writing business logic in templates. [Jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/) however is a template processor that allows to make function calls and subscripting. But typically if you need these in a template, then this is a sign that something might be wrong with the design.